# Update AOSP built-in system app

Tags: android, build, android-source

Lets say we have downloaded, built and flashed AOSP source code. Now a change to a system app is made (e.g. changed a constant in the packages/apps/Nfc package).

The next step is to build it, and there are two ways to do it:

```
cd packages/apps/Nfc; mm
```

or

```
mmm Nfc
```

This will create out/target/product//system/app/NfcNci/NfcNci.apk file

**Which is the proper way to update the system app?**

I tried using *adb install NfcNci.apk* but no success:

```
~/android/aosp-7.1.2-3.10-v2/out/target/product/kugo/system/app/NfcNci$ adb install NfcNci.apk
Failed to install NfcNci.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install com.android.nfcnci without first uninstalling.]
~/android/aosp-7.1.2-3.10-v2/out/target/product/kugo/system/app/NfcNci$ adb install -r NfcNci.apk
Failed to install NfcNci.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.android.nfcnci-1: Package /data/app/com.android.nfcnci-1/base.apk code is missing]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a way to easily 're-install' the app itself (let's put Settings app as an example):

```
mmm packages/apps/Settings  # Build the module
adb root ; adb remount  # Restart adbd as root and mount /system as writable
adb push out/target/product/<device_name>/system/priv-app/Settings /system/priv-app  # Push the built files to the device
```

Then force-close and restart the app (by swiping it from *Recents*). No need to reboot device in order to take changes

NOTE: Depending on the app, the path may be on `system/app` instead of `/system/priv-app`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to:

1. copy the new apk to the sdcard of the device with `adb push`
2. mount /system read write: `mount -o rw,remount,rw /system`
3. copy your new .apk from /sdcard over your old .apk in /system/app
4. remove the .odex file of your old .apk
5. reboot the device

For development you can use a simple script for this steps.

Answer (score 0):

Check **build/envsetup.sh** file - there's also commands `mmp` and `mmmp` to build and push a module to connected device. Also `adb sync` can be used to sync whole image, so if you updated a module, changed files will be pushed to device.

Also you can put the changed files via regular `adb push' and reboot device.

I do not know if system apps can be updated via `adb install`, probably yes, but I think you need to increment build number in the manifest file.

I do not think you can uninstall a system app with `adb install -r`, as apps can't be removed from `system` partition, only from `data`. I do not know why you are getting INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK in that case, may be because app manager can't uninstall the base system apk indeed.